# convert a comma separated string to json in java

Tags: java, string, java-8

I have a comma separated string which needs to converted into a JSON string, When I make the JSONArray conversion it is still in array format. What is the best way to solve this.

```
String str="art,0.0, comedy,0.0, action,0.0, crime,0.0, animals,0.0"
```

expected output

```
{"art":"0.0", "comedy":"0.0","action":"0.0","crime":"0.0","animals":"0.0"}
```

Here is the code I tried

```
String [] arrayStr=strVal.split(",");
JSONArray mJSONArray = new JSONArray();
for (String s: arrayStr){
    mJSONArray.put(s);
}
System.out.println(mJSONArray.toString());
```

output

```
["art","0.0"," comedy","0.0"," action","0.0"," crime","0.0"," animals","0.0"]
```

Comment: You want a `Map`, not an array. After having your array, group the elements in key/value pairs inside a map.

Comment: Your expected output is a JSON *object*, not a JSON *array*, so why are you using `JSONArray`? Perhaps you should learn a bit more about [JSON](http://json.org/) before you try to generate it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For such a trivial example, it's pretty easy to produce a poorly-formed JSON `String` of your content and let `JSONObject` patch it up.

In a single expression:

```
new JSONObject(String.format("{%s}", str.replaceAll("([^,]+),([^,]+)(,|$)", "$1:$2,")))
// {"art":0,"comedy":0,"action":0,"crime":0,"animals":0}
```

If you really want to keep the `0.0` as `String`s:

```
new JSONObject(String.format("{%s}", str.replaceAll("([^,]+),([^,]+)(,|$)", "$1:\"$2\",")))
// {"art":"0.0","comedy":"0.0","action":"0.0","crime":"0.0","animals":"0.0"}
```

If you want to account for possible extraneous whitespaces:

```
new JSONObject(String.format("{%s}", str.replaceAll("([^,]+)\\s*?,\\s*?([^,]+)(,|$)", "$1:$2,")))
```

.. will work with inputs like `"art, 0.0, comedy, 0.0, action, 0.0, crime, 0.0, animals, 0.0"` and other cases.

---

Disclaimer: it's not crazy-sexy code but drop in a one-line comment and it could be reasonable so long as the data structure stays simplistic.

Comment: I like this approach, without no additional libraries to import, but on the downside all those wildcards symbols needs totally new education !

Comment: Good Solution. But can be made more informative if added some descriptions?

Answer (score 2):

You should use Map instead of Array (List of key/value pair is Map, not Array).

**1 way: Using JsonObject**

```
String [] arrayStr=strVal.split(",");
JsonObjectBuilder builder = Json.createObjectBuilder()

String key = null;
for (String s: arrayStr){
    if(key == null) {
       key = s;
    } else {
       builder.add(key, s);
       key = null;
    }
}
JsonObject value = builder.build();
```

**2 way: Using Map**

```
String [] arrayStr=strVal.split(",");
Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<>();

String key = null;
for (String s: arrayStr){
    if(key == null) {
       key = s;
    } else {
       map.put(key, s);
       key = null;
    }
}

// convert Map to Json using any Json lib (Gson, Jackson and so on)
```

Comment: Question doesn't say which JSON library is used, and neither do you, but question uses `JSONArray` and you use `JsonObject`, so you're definitely not referring to the same JSON library *(notice difference in upper/lower-case of class name)*.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to use JSONObject not JSONArray to get the desired output.  i.e. just add the items to the object - jsonObject.put(key, value)